# How can I make IntelliJ IDEA understand my null-checking method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullable

I have a method where a parameter is marked with the `@Nonnull` annotation. The code which calls the method has to check whether the value is null. Rather than just a straight `x != null` check, it is calling a utility method on another class. (In the real code, the utility method also checks whether it is a blank String).

My problem is that Intellij Idea is showing an inspection warning on the Nonnull method call, saying that my variable "might be null". I know it cannot be null because of the utility method check - how can I tell the inspector that?

Since that is a bit abstract, here's a minimal example of what I mean:

```java
package org.ethelred.ideatest;

import javax.annotation.CheckForNull;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

/**
 * tests annotations
 */
public class AnnotationChecker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x = null;
        if(args.length > 0)
        {
            x = args[0];
        }

        if(!isNull(x))
        {
            useObject(x);
        }

        if(x != null)
        {
            useObject(x);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNull(@CheckForNull Object o)
    {
        return o == null;
    }


    public static void useObject(@Nonnull Object o)
    {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

This uses the JSR 305 annotations.

In this example, in the *first* call to `useObject` Intellij puts a warning on the `x` parameter saying "Argument 'x' might be null". In the *second* call, there is no warning.

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this? Why not use `x != null`?

Comment: Just because your compiler has a warning doesn't mean you should change your code.  Perhaps you could use an appropriate `@SuppressWarnings()` annotation?  On the other hand, if your function is just `s != null && s.length () != 0`, perhaps a separate function isn't really saving you much.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the example given is simplified. In the real code, the null check is in a method which checks for other things as well.

Comment: when you (right?) click on the warning (i think - somehow...) you can get a menu that often allows disabling of specific checks (i think this is a perfectly valid q and it bugs the heck out of me when people say "don't do that" to valid qs - do they really think you don't know you can "not do it"?!)

Comment: The keystroke to show intention actions and quick-fixes on Windows is `Alt-Enter`.  You can also reach them by clicking on the lightbulb icon that appears if you place the cursor just after the `x` that is highlighted with the warning. The options that appear in this case are `Assert 'x != null'` and `Surround with 'if (x != null)'`.  In some cases there is an option to add an appropriate `SuppressWarnings` annotation to the statement, but there's no supported value for that annotation to suppress this warning so it isn't included in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to resolve the warning with the code written as it is.  I was hoping to find that IntelliJ supports a value for `@SuppressWarnings` that you could use on the `useObject(x)` statement, but according to [this source](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html) it does not. You may just have to bite the bullet and change your code to something like the following:

```
if (x != null && !isBlank(x)) {
    useObject(x);
}
```

Notice that I renamed the method `isNull` to `isBlank` since it is my understanding that the actual method you're calling that does the check for `null` checks other conditions as well.

Answer (score 12):

In IDEA 13 very fancy feature was added, called [Method Contracts](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/better-control-flow-analysis-with-contract-annotations-and-intellij-idea-13/). For example, you could have a method, that throws validation exception if it encounters null:

```
@Contract("null -> fail")
public static void validateNull(@Nullable final Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new ValidationException();
    }
}
```

IDEA will analyze the annotation and won't show up warnings, if you call it before possible NPE:

```
validateNull(user);
user.setSomething("something"); // no warning
```

You have full documentation in IDEA's settings (just search for Method Contract). For this to work you need additional dependency on jetbrain's annotations jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

With IDEA 12 you can configure the NotNull-check methods:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-35808#tab=Comments

Answer (score -2):

I've dealt with this issue by using a static method to whitelist object calls:

```
/** Wrapper to mask NullPointerException warnings. */
private static <T> T _(T obj) {

    return obj;
}
```

The method name is intended to not interfere with readability. Thus,

```
mObject.method();
```

becomes

```
_(mObject).method();
```

Furthermore, if a NullPointerException does occur it will still refer to the same line number.