# Intellij null checking: unreachable statements

Tags: java, intellij-idea, null

*This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636483/how-can-i-make-intellij-idea-understand-my-null-checking-method), but the focus is somewhat different*

I have a function that loads a file on disk in a try catch block. Because the file is crucial to the program, it will terminate if it fails to load the file:

```
String loadSuperImportantFile() {
    try {
        // ... file loading code ...
        assert fileContent != null;
        return fileContent;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load super important file. Please check path.");
        System.exit(Codes.FAIL); // terminate the program
    }
    return null; // statement is unreachable
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize that it is impossible for this function to return null. Because of this, I get warnings whenever I use the return string:

```
foo(loadSuperImportantFile()); // WARNING: Argument "loadSuperImportantFile()" might be null.
```

From reading the question I linked up above, I believe it may be possible to use Method Contracts to tell IntelliJ that the method cannot return null. I tried using the `@Contract("null -> fail")` decorator, but the warnings did not disappear.

Does anyone have an ideas on how to make the warnings disappear in the method itself, using a Method Contract or something similar, rather than null checking externally?

Comment: Is the "file loading code"  able to throw an `IOException` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.exit(Codes.FAIL);` is not a terminating statement in Java (like `return` or `throw`).

In some wired cases, you could imagine, that it is possible to override `exit` method (or mock it), in such a way it doesn't terminate the application. Then this `null` would be returned.

For a concise and robust application, if you want to terminate the application, throw an Exception that would propagate up. Especially, if you want to terminate your application **because** an error occurred (invalid path). It would be even more pragmatic, to let the application die on it's own. Why do you have to call `System.exit();`?

PS: You can also see the answers of @Stephen C or @user31601, and that would surely fix your problem with method returning `null` (because it uses flow control statement - `throw`), but I wouldn't suggest that option. In my opinion, it would be better to *design* a better structue, one that is concise, and doesn't let such situation occur - in opposite to allow it to happen, and then throw `AssertionException` when it does.

PS2: You could also add `@NotNull` like @yole suggested, but again - instead of **reacting** to thing that **shouldn't** happen - just don't let it happen. And throw (for example) `throw new InvalidPathException();`.

My suggestion:

```
String loadSuperImportantFile() {
    try {
        return fileContent;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        throw new ImportantFileMissingException("Failed to load super important file. Please check path.");
    }
}

class ImportantFileMissingException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Comment: That is very surprising, as in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)) it says "Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine." Does that mean that statements AFTER `exit()` can still be run?

Comment: @Campbell yes, it does terminate the application, but from the parser perspective, it's just a method (that can be overriden or mocked). Application control structure (like if, while, return, throw, catch) is probably a way to go.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very good explanation and clear example.

Comment: So to recap, `Does that mean that statements AFTER exit() can still be run?` - from the runtime perspective - No. From the parser and/or compiler perspective - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> IntelliJ IDEA does not recognize that it is impossible for this function to return `null`.

IntelliJ is simply following the standard Java reachability rules.  These say that the `return null;` statement is reachable.

> Does anyone have an ideas on how to make the warnings disappear in the method itself.

You could replace the last statement with this:

```
   throw new AssertionError("unreachable statement executed");
```

Or better still, put it after the `System.exit(...)` call.

Any unchecked exception would do, but to my mind an `AssertionError` is the strongest indication that something totally wrong has happened.  Note that you need to explicitly throw the exception.  Using an `assert` is not sufficient to avoid the need for a `return` ... since assertion checking can be turned off.

The runtime cost of a `throw` statement that is never executed is minimal to zero.

Another idea is to return a dummy non-null value.  In this example, an empty string would do.

---

The problem with annotating the method as `@NotNull` is that a static code analyzer (using the same incomplete logic as IntelliJ) may flag that the method *does* return `null`.  If you can suppress that warning, there is also the possibility that some framework might insert a runtime check for `null` ... which 1) serves no purpose and 2) maybe can't be optimized away.

---

Unfortunately, there is no practical way to tag `System.exit` with an annotation that says "this statement never returns".   Why?  Because it is a standard method, and you can't change it ... without hacking the class libraries and (potentially) breaking portability.

The best you can do (I think) to fix the problem would be to develop and submit a patch to the Intellij maintainers.  One that "understands" the special behavior of `System.exit`.

---

Finally, it is generally speaking a bad idea for a library method to call `System.exit` in a method like in your example.  A better approach is to throw a custom exception which you catch at / near the base of the call stack ... on the application's controlling thread.  That way, you can have all of the code and logic that governs (controlled) application exit in the same place.

A subsidiary method should not be deciding about the "fate" of the overall application.

Comment: Your last point is very good and makes a lot of sense. That will definitely be the route I take in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a terminating statement to the end of catch block? It will never be reached, so all it should do is help the compiler infer that the final return statement isn't necessary.

For example:

```
String loadSuperImportantFile() {
    try {
        // ... file loading code ...
        assert fileContent != null;
        return fileContent;
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to load super important file. Please check path.");
        System.exit(Codes.FAIL); // terminate the program
        throw new AssertionError("Unreachable");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Placing the throw statement *outside* of the catch block doesn't work though. Do you know why?

Comment: What happens when you place the `throw` statement outside?

Comment: Same thing ... except that the code is a bit more fragile.  Consider what happens if you add a second `catch` that *doesn't* call `System.exit`.

Comment: Well, the OP has stated that it _doesn't_ work with the `throw` statement outside the `catch`, so I was asking them what they saw (i.e. what was the compiler error). As far as I can see, it should still work (although I accept @StephenC's statement that it is more fragile).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the context.  But I think the OP is wrong about `throw` at the end not working.

Comment: @user31601 By "doesn't work" I mean that the warning is still there. Placing the throw statement outside the catch block is seen as no different than returning null by IntelliJ.

Comment: So what's the line of code that the compiler is complaining about? Do you still have a `return null;` statement? The whole point is that throwing the exception means you can _remove_ that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply annotate the method as `@NotNull`. The `@Contract` annotation you've tried to apply says that the method will fail if you pass `null` to it as a parameter, which does not make sense because it does not have any parameters.

Comment: Some probably see this as bad practice. Because the method could technically return null if you managed to prevent System.exit from terminating the program, and @NotNull simply hides the warning instead of playing safe.

Comment: The question was "how to make IntelliJ highlight this code correctly?", not "how to deal with the crazy deed of someone patching System.exit so that it doesn't exit?".

Comment: That's fair, but I feel that the best answer to a problem is more valuable than the right answer to a poor question. Not really sure why you deserved the down vote though.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't consider assuming that `System.exit` does indeed terminate the execution to be a bad practice. And IntelliJ IDEA's code analysis, at least in recent versions, does recognize that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also return an `Optional<String>` instead of a `String`.

This way, you could avoid returning `null` and return an `Optional.empty()` instead to avoid null checking and possible `NullPointerException`.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html